# trying to call solidity function but getting error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM

Tags: web3js

```
(node:23725) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0xefa94e2c8243a7bcfef067fedd89bcc497b5844b398c764150231425b2547376",
  "blockNumber": 2212,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 21634,
  "from": "0x5c56bf111b3f894efae992e34a7be5be38950399",
  "gasUsed": 21634,
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0x82d666f1a6f307fe38761b4842e78422db1d4b7a",
  "transactionHash": "0x32a78305a48e4598d4527bb35aa67b2538732469b02087ac1af148259dc56b5f",
  "transactionIndex": 0,
  "events": {}
}
```

My smart contract is :

```
pragma solidity = 0.5.12;

contract MyContract {
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;
    address payable wallet;

    event Purchase(
        address indexed _buyer,
        uint256 amount
    );

    constructor(address payable _wallet) public {
        wallet = _wallet;
    }

    function buyToken(uint256 amount) public payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += amount;
        wallet.transfer(msg.value);
        emit Purchase(msg.sender, amount);
    }
}
```

and i am calling the smart contract function using web3:

```
 web3js = new web3(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8543"));

    abiDefinition = JSON.parse(variables.MyContractJSON);

    contractInstance =  new web3js.eth.Contract(abiDefinition,"0x82D666f1a6f307FE38761b4842E78422DB1d4B7A");
    // In your nodejs console, execute contractInstance.address to get the address at which the contract is deployed and change the line below to use your deployed address
   // contractInstance = MyContract.at("0x82D666f1a6f307FE38761b4842E78422DB1d4B7A");
    app.post("/buyToken", multipartMiddleware, function(req, res, next) { 
        console.log('In crud::buyToken::::::'); 
        var timeStamp = Date.now();
        //var amount = parseInt(req.body.amount);
        var sender = variables.sender_1;
         var pass = variables.pass;

      contractInstance.methods.buyToken("15").send({
            //console.log()
         from: sender,
         gas: 470000,
         gasPrice:0
        },function(e,result){
                if (e) {
                console.error("Got error for doing the function call buyToken:::::::::");
                console.error(e);
                return;
                // callback fires twice, we only want the second call when the contract is deployed
            } else if (result) {
                console.log('Successfully buyToken.');
                console.log('Transaction hash : ' + result);
                res.json(result)
            } else {
                console.log("Please Contact Administrator...It should never come here.")
            }
        });


    });
```

Note: I have variables.js in which sender assress lies.

Comment: Where exactly in your code are you actually deploying this contract, and how do you know that it is at address `0x82d666f1a6f307fe38761b4842e78422db1d4b7a`?

Comment: Are you testing against ganache or a private testnet? What type of wallet are you using?

Comment: I solved it.i was passing gas price 0 and was not passing the value field.